# English version of a paper by Gusarov

Tags: reference-request, gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, translation

I am looking for the english translation of the paper in russian [Variations of knotted graphs, geometric technique of n-equivalence, St. Petersburg Math. J. 12-4 (2001)](https://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=aa&paperid=1116&option_lang=eng) by Gusarov.

There is a .ps file on [Dror Bar-Natan website](https://www.math.toronto.edu/%7Edrorbn/Goussarov/) but I am unable to read the file. I already tried reading it with a postscript reader, or converting it to a pdf file.

Would someone have the english translation of that paper, that they could send to me? Or would someone know of a place where I could find it?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14uqJjQ8a8Cckza5ctofDJF6c4k_Zxs0O/view?usp=sharing). I put the paper into pdf format; it looks ok to me. I didn't have any trouble reading the original postscript file with ghostscript on Ubuntu. If you can't read the pdf or the postscript file, maybe your computer is misbehaving.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your link works perfectly! Indeed, there might have been a problem in the conversion.